# need a sql query for shorting by particular column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query is like this I have a table products1 where all fields are filled if I used to search the results using filters i am getting the results if all the filters are selected if I select only two filters like category and prodstatus it displays results with category and prodstatus with mixing with all results I need a result like it should filter based on category, if only that category have prodstatus of what we select it should display only that,

below is my query

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM products1 WHERE Category='$Category' and prodstatus='$prodstatus' and productsize between '$product_size'-30 and '$product_size' and productprice between '$product_min_price'-999 and '$product_min_price'";

 if($Category && $prodstatus  && $product_size && $product_min_price >0)  {
    $result1 = mysql_query("$sql1") or die(mysql_error());
   ....
 }
```

Comment: Please provide more code (what happens after this `if` statement you show, how do the filter variables get their values...). When are the filters considered to be 'selected'? Your current `if` condition seems odd, on the other hand apparently requiring all filter values to be present, but then you say you don't want to have to 'select' all filters. And yet you still get a result when you do not 'select' all filters? Some example data, together with current (incorrect) results and desired (correct) results might help. As a bonus, some punctuation would be nice.

Comment: Please provide a  minimal, complete and verifiable example. See [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)